# refresh an expired access token using oauth framework afnetworking ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking

I have a simple Login page where I input username and password and I validate login using `AFOAuth2Manager` of `AFNetworking` and my server returns success or failure depending on the result.I have the `OAuth` information stored in an `AFOAuthCredential` object that has access token and refresh token.

But I dont know how can I refresh the access token using refresh token once the access token expires. 
I cant find good documentation on this.
Please help.

Comment: After a year, have you found the solution now? If you do, please share yours. If you don't, I suggest doing stuff like create an interceptor. Let's research this together!